# How to get Dropbox chooser working as a Sharepoint 2010 Visual Webpart

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have the javascript code below in a SP2010 visual webpart which works in Google Chrome but not in IE9. This is a worry as the Dropbox Chooser website says that the addEventListener doesn't work for IE8 or lower.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DropboxControlUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="DropBoxWebPart.DropboxControl.DropboxControlUserControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
     function(e) {
         window.open(e.files[0].link)
     }, false);
</script>
```

I have tried to use the Dropbox.chooser(options) function to overcome this but I am not sure where to put the code or call the function from. Do I need to call it from the codebehind as I have tried to put it in a script like this and also tried using document.getElementById("db-chooser").on or .attachevent and couldn't get it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropbox.chooser(options);
options = {

        // Required. Called when a user selects an item in the Chooser.
        success: function(files) {
            alert("Here's the file link:" + files[0].link)
        },

        // Optional. Called when the user closes the dialog without selecting a file
        // and does not include any parameters.
        cancel: function() {

        },

        linkType: "preview" or "direct",     

        extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx'],            
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that your first example doesn't work in IE9. It looks fine to me. I'll try it myself later. (**EDIT**: I did get a chance to try this, though it was on IE10 in IE9 mode. The code worked fine for me.)

For your second example, you're not defining `options` until *after* you've passed it as a parameter. (So you're passing an undefined variable and then defining it later.) If you just put the `Dropbox.choose(options);` line after you've actually defined that variable, I would expect it to work.

Also, that `linkType` is invalid. Pick one, either "preview" or "direct". To start, try this code:

```
var options = {
    success: function (files) { alert(files[0].link); }
}
Dropbox.choose(options);
```

or, if you prefer:

```
Dropbox.choose({
    success: function (files) { alert(files[0].link); }
});
```

You'll want to run that code in response to a user action (like clicking a link) so you don't get blocked by pop-up blockers. So something like this:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').onclick = function () {
    Dropbox.choose({
        success: function (files) { alert(files[0].link); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks smarx your examples worked perfectly. I also found out my 1st example didn't work because my Sharepoint Masterpages had a script to converted it to use IE8 standards. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>